# Phone LED only flashes for a few minutes after receiving a notification

Tags: htc-desire, notifications

My HTC Desire is set up to flash its LED lamp whenever I receive an email, SMS etc.

Only problem is that (without touching the phone) the LED stops flashing after 5 minutes or so. So if a message comes in while I'm not near my phone and I don't come back for more than 5 minutes, I have to turn on the screen to discover the message.

I've searched through everything, but there seems to be no setting for this.

Am I missing something, or is this by design? Is there an app for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must be by design. Flashing the LED infinitely would drain the battery (even if only slightly). I don't see anything in Settings regarding lengthening the amount of time the LED will flash; you can only specify what things cause LED notification.

After some searching it looks like the "Missed Reminder" app allows for a lot of notification customization - LED interval, color, etc. Not sure how to link an app so just search for it in the market. Sounds promising. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the my Moto Droid started doing this with the latest Android 2.2.  The notification icon stays in the notification area, but the LED stops flashing.  Personally, I like this behavior, but I don't know of any way to prevent it from "silencing" the blinking LED.  Seems to be by design, and seems to be for the latest versions of Android.