# Can I change the time interval between flashes of the notification led on the HTC incredible?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, notification-led, notifications

I want to be able to change the time interval between flashes of the LED when I have a new notification. Is this possible on the HTC Incredible running 2.1 (eclair) or even on 2.2 (froyo)?

I don't really want to flash my device or install a custom build of android, etc.

Answer (score 3):

My answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/393/phone-led-only-flashes-for-a-few-minutes-after-receiving-a-notification/397#397) for a similar question points to the [Missed Reminder app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/missed-reminder/ru.orangesoftware.areminder) which appears to have an adjustable LED interval setting. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I've only seen this feature on rooted Android phones running custom ROMs.

I've seen it on some custom ROMs in the 'Messaging' app, but never as a general system-wide setting. I'm going to say that no, this isn't possible right now, at least on stock Android.